# Why is my formula returning a number instead of a date?

Tags: date, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

When trying to add days to a date in another column the value returns as a number, not a date.

I have tried to set the column format as the date for both columns B and C. I also tried using the `DATEVALUE()` function, but I don't think I used it properly.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(B:B)=1,"Second Notification",IF(LEN(B:B), B:B+1,)))
```

I want the value in column C to return as a date.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NaOt_wzQ8futpj7FpiuTWRUvcmzc1ORGdNj93drYSRQ/edit#gid=780949073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this with `TEXT` formula:

```
={"Second Notification"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), TEXT(B2:B+1, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), ))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You people are all amazing.